# Change of arrival state in the US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I have been granted an immigrant visa to the US already. I am going/migrating to Minnesota, USA because my mom/petitioner, resides there. Our plan is, after I arrive in MN, we are going to my sister that lives in Kentucky USA just for a vacation to see my other families there.

The question is, can I just fly straight to kentucky instead of Minnesota even though Minnesota address was what I put already initially on all my forms and documents and told the embassy already during my visa interview that I would go to Minnesota because that’s where my petitioner lives? Is that ok to just book a flight straight to kentucky or do I have to really go to Minnesota first because that’s where my address I said I was going to go is?

Comment: For those voting to close, this really has nothing to do with immigrating and belongs here far more than it belongs on Expats.  That said, it is a dup if someone could be bothered to dig up one of the dozen other times this has been asked before...

Comment: Given your most probably won’t fly directly to either state, but will more likely stop in some other state first, and you clear immigration at your first port of entry, I would expect it to make no difference. The CBP officer may ask questions, though, just explain the things as they are.

Answer (score 2):

The port of entry you use to enter the US with your immigrant visa is not relevant. You can use [any port of entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/the-immigrant-visa-process/interview/after-the-interview.html) which accepts foreign visitors by air or land. Keep in mind that it will take extra time to process your immigration to the US, so you should leave an extra hour or so between your connecting flights, above what you would normally do.

Comment: Arriving with an immigrant visa at a sea port is also okay, if a little unusual!